# Display data from FQL

Tags: jsp, facebook-fql, photo

```
String query = "SELECT pid, src_big FROM photo WHERE owner=" + yourUid;
    List<JsonObject> queryResults = 
    facebookClient.executeFqlQuery(query, JsonObject.class);
```

After I have done this in my servlet, how should I retrieve the data such as pid and src_big in my jsp page?

```
<c:forEach items="${photosList}" var="photo">
    //what should I type here to retrieve the data?
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by looping through the list of JsonObject, then I retrieved the src_big data and stored them separately on another list of String (photosList).

```
<c:forEach items="${photosList}" var="photo">
    <img src='${photo}' height="250" width="250" />
</c:forEach>
```